# Appcelerator Titanium doesn't start on my Mac

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java.library.path

I've tried to run appcelerator Titanium Studio on my Mac but it give me this error (I've deleted and reinstalled the TitaniumStudio.app, java, workpspace directory..)

My OS is Osx Mavericks, jdk-7u45, last version of Titanium studio (3.2.0)

Any Suggestions?
Thanks!

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/tarzariol/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/tarzariol/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-01-10 13:18:35.551
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-01-10 13:18:36.181
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the images from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commandImages' extension point.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-01-10 13:18:36.182
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.appcelerator.titanium.android.ui', id='com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.command.run_on_device.android'
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-01-10 13:18:36.182
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.appcelerator.titanium.android.ui', id='com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.command.debug_on_device.android'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-01-10 13:18:43.428
!MESSAGE A

pplication error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no osx in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.apple.eio.FileManager.<clinit>(FileManager.java:58)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at com.aptana.core.internal.platform.CoreMacOSX.FileManager_findFolder(CoreMacOSX.java:35)
    at com.aptana.core.util.PlatformUtil.expandEnvironmentStrings(PlatformUtil.java:524)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2590)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Comment: Could you give more info on what's installed and versions.  Maybe include info on OS, Xcode, node, Titanium IDE SDK CLI, and Java.

Comment: of course!, My OS is Osx Mavericks, jdk-7u45, last version of Titanium studio (3.2.0)

Comment: Did you have the Eclipse tools installed prior to your update.  I have the same items installed as you plus Eclipse tools Kepler.